# Compiling Windows Store C++ App for ARM

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, arm

I've created a new Hub App for Windows Store on C++ in Visual Studio. But i have following questions:

Is it correct that it includes "windows.h", "debugapi.h" etc and links windows libraries? Can i compile under ARM processor with them? Is there a possibility to develop on C++ for x86,x64 AND arm?

I go to Project Settings > Advanced > Target Platform and set this option to ARM. After this, i having compiler error on App.xaml.obj:

```
error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'ARM'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change target platform to ARM correctly, i had to switch project configuration : target platform, instead of touching Linker options' Target Machine option, and clean solution.